# How to find out more about the Cloud TPU device you are running your programs against?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-tpu

Whether we are using Google Colab or accessing Cloud TPUs directly, the below program gives only limited information about the underlying TPUs:

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf

tpu_address = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
print ('TPU address is', tpu_address)

def printTPUDevices():
   with tf.Session(tpu_address) as session:
      devices = session.list_devices()

      print ('TPU devices:')
      return devices

printTPUDevices()
```

Is there any documentation of programmatically or via bash commands to display more information, see this gist for e.g. https://gist.github.com/neomatrix369/256913dcf77cdbb5855dd2d7f5d81b84.

Comment: Thanks Rajiv for amending the tag to the more appropriate tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud TPU system architecture is a bit different from GPU's so this level of information is not available.

Because the client talks to a remote TensorFlow [server](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/system-architecture#software_architecture) and uses [XLA](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/xla/g3doc/overview.md), client code doesn't need to change based on the available features on the TPU, the remote server will compile machine instructions based on the TPU's capabilities.

However the [Cloud TPU Profiler](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/cloud-tpu-tools) does give a lower level view of the TPU for performance optimization. You can see a trace level view of what operations are using up memory and compute time.

Comment: Thanks @michaelb, I have come across the Cloud TPU profile although it seems some setup is needed before we can use it.

Is there a easier/shorter way to use it via Google Colab.

Comment: I'm working on this aspect of the TPU - on my reading list, thanks for the tips